# Having issue regarding the socket in my server and the client side android application

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

we are trying to connect the socket through https server and that was working perfectly fine few days back after that our ssl certificate expire on the server so we just use Let's encrypt to get the free ssl for our server and after that we ran into trouble.
And also we are using socket with socket.io-redis
package version in nodejs:-
"socket.io": "^1.7.3",
"socket.io-redis": "^4.0.0",

package version in android:-

io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3
our application is not connecting from the socket rest everthing is working fine.
one application we are getting the error of;
io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

Also i am providing the server side code please help me as soon as possible
backend in nodejs
client side android (application)

nodejs code

````
var https = require("https");
 var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT),
  }, app);
} else {
  var server = http.createServer(app);
}
global.io = require('socket.io')(server,{ rejectUnauthorized: false });
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6478,
}));
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('...........................socket connected', socket);
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this demo code for setup socket io with node and express this may help you to fix your issue

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: this works for ip but i am using ssl on my server.